# Waterfall chart status flip issue with JSON Model

Tags: javascript, json, charts, sapui5

I have created a waterfall chart in UI5 using Viz library.

**JSON data for Waterfall Chart is as below:**

```
{ "Rowsets" : { 
    "DateCreated" : "2017-03-27T19:20:57", "Version" : "15.1 SP2 Patch 5 (Jul 20, 2016)", "StartDate" : "2017-03-27T18:20:55-0500", "EndDate" : "2017-03-27T19:20:55-0500", "CachedTime" : "", 
    "Rowset" : [ 
    { "Columns" : { 
        "Column" : [ 
        { "Name" : "Status", "SourceColumn" : "Status", "Description" : "", "SQLDataType" : 1, "MinRange" : 1.0, "MaxRange" : 1.0 }, 
        { "Name" : "Hours", "SourceColumn" : "Hours", "Description" : "", "SQLDataType" : 8, "MinRange" : 1.0, "MaxRange" : 1.0 }, 
        { "Name" : "Type", "SourceColumn" : "Type", "Description" : "", "SQLDataType" : 1, "MinRange" : 1.0, "MaxRange" : 1.0 } ] }, 
    "Row" : [ 
        { "Status" : "Full Production Time", "Hours" : 7.85, "Type" : "null" }, 
        { "Status" : "Quality Loss", "Hours" : 0.15, "Type" : "null" }, 
        { "Status" : "Net Run Time", "Hours" : 8.00, "Type" : "subtotal:2" }, 
        { "Status" : "Performance Loss", "Hours" : 69.00, "Type" : "null" }, 
        { "Status" : "Run Time", "Hours" : 77.00, "Type" : "subtotal:2" }, 
        { "Status" : "Unplanned DownTime", "Hours" : 76.00, "Type" : "null" }, 
        { "Status" : "Scheduled Time", "Hours" : 153.00, "Type" : "subtotal:2" }, 
        { "Status" : "Planned DownTime", "Hours" : 15.00, "Type" : "null" }, 
        { "Status" : "Available Time", "Hours" : 168.00, "Type" : "subtotal:2" }, 
        { "Status" : "Total Time", "Hours" : 168.00, "Type" : "subtotal:1" } ]
         } ]
     }
 }
```

Waterfall Chart:

[image]

**The View of the waterfall chart:**

```
<l:FixFlex id='chartFixFlex' minFlexSize="250">
<l:flexContent>
<viz:Popover id="idPopOver">
</viz:Popover>
<viz:VizFrame id="idVizFrame" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}"
height='100%' width="100%" vizType='horizontal_waterfall'>
<viz:dataset>
<viz.data:FlattenedDataset
data="{/Rowsets/Rowset/0/Row}">
<viz.data:dimensions>
<viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Type" value="{Type}" />
<viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Status" value="{Status}" />
</viz.data:dimensions>
<viz.data:measures>
<viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Hours" value="{Hours}" />
</viz.data:measures>
</viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
</viz:dataset>
<viz:feeds>
<viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="valueAxis" type="Measure" values="Hours" />
<viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension" values="Status" />
<viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="waterfallType" type="Dimension" values="Type" />
</viz:feeds>
</viz:VizFrame>
</l:flexContent>
</l:FixFlex>
```

**The controller of the waterfall chart:**

```
var sURL = ** URL whihc brings bak above mentioned JSON Data **
var oChartModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel;
oChartModel.loadData(sURL,{},false);

var oVizFrame = this.oVizFrame = this.byId("idVizFrame");

oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
    plotArea : {
        dataLabel : {
            visible : true
        }
    },

    valueAxis : {

        title : {
            visible : true
        }
    },

    categoryAxis : {
        title : {
            visible : true
        }
    },

    legend: {
                            title: {
                                visible: false
                            },
                            label: {
                                text: {
                                      positiveValue: "Hours"
                                }
                            }
    },

    title : {
        visible : true,
        text : 'Waterfall Chart'
    }

});

oVizFrame.setModel(oChartModel);
```

Now, the chart looks ok and functioning fine. But I got the requirement that the chart needs to show statuses in reverse order - basically all the statuses should flip. Total Time should come at the top and Full Production should come at the bottom.

As per my logic, in waterfall chart every status is subtotal of above few statuses depending upon the condition as shown in JSON Data. So now to flip the statuses, I am not able to figure out how should my JSON data should look like so that statuses appear in reverse order and a correct format.

Any feedback or suggestions?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to flip the order by readjusting my JSON data.

My new JSON is as below:

```
{ "Rowsets" : { 
    "DateCreated" : "2017-03-27T19:40:28", "Version" : "15.1 SP2 Patch 5 (Jul 20, 2016)", "StartDate" : "2017-03-27T18:40:26-0500", "EndDate" : "2017-03-27T19:40:26-0500", "CachedTime" : "", 
    "Rowset" : [ 
    { "Columns" : { 
        "Column" : [ 
        { "Name" : "Status", "SourceColumn" : "Status", "Description" : "", "SQLDataType" : 1, "MinRange" : 1.0, "MaxRange" : 1.0 }, 
        { "Name" : "Hours", "SourceColumn" : "Hours", "Description" : "", "SQLDataType" : 8, "MinRange" : 1.0, "MaxRange" : 1.0 }, 
        { "Name" : "Type", "SourceColumn" : "Type", "Description" : "", "SQLDataType" : 1, "MinRange" : 1.0, "MaxRange" : 1.0 } ] }, 
    "Row" : [ 
        { "Status" : "Total Time", "Hours" : 168.00, "Type" : "total" }, 
        { "Status" : "Available Time", "Hours" : 168.00, "Type" : "total" }, 
        { "Status" : "Planned DownTime", "Hours" : -15.00, "Type" : "null" }, 
        { "Status" : "Scheduled Time", "Hours" : 153.00, "Type" : "subtotal:1" }, 
        { "Status" : "Unplanned DownTime", "Hours" : -76.00, "Type" : "null" }, 
        { "Status" : "Run Time", "Hours" : 77.00, "Type" : "subtotal:1" }, 
        { "Status" : "Performance Loss", "Hours" : -69.00, "Type" : "null" }, 
        { "Status" : "Net Run Time", "Hours" : 8.00, "Type" : "subtotal:1" }, 
        { "Status" : "Quality Loss", "Hours" : -0.15, "Type" : "null" }, 
        { "Status" : "Full Production Time", "Hours" : 7.85, "Type" : "subtotal:1" } ]
         } ]
     }
 }
```

I hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your current JSON file?
Have you seen [Sample: Waterfall - Horizontal](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.viz.sample.Waterfall/preview) ?
If you ignore the top bars from “Restaurant” to “Retail” and swap/flip the legend at the vertical axis, is this the graphic you are looking for ?
You might also switch the Dataset from “Small” to “Medium” back and forth.

You can look at the corresponding coding for this sample.
If you switch to debugger and display “Network”, you also can find the corresponding .json files used for this sample when changing the Dataset to “Small” or “Medium”.

Comment: My JSON is already added in the question. I just need to swap statuses in my chart but for Type I'm using subtotal:1 / subtotal:2 etc which totals above items 1 or 2 but now if i flip it I cant pass that. IS thre any opposite of subtotal for waterfall chart type?

Comment: “Flip”-feature as requested by you is currently not supported.